# How to move a div with slight lag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a Jquery animation in which I want to animate a balloon to move off screen. I have figured out the movement part. But, I couldn't quite figure out how to make it move realistically with slight lags as a real balloon.

The `.animate()` function moves the element in linear motion.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#section").click(function() {
    $('.parachute').animate({bottom: "1500px"}, 5000);
  });
});
```

How should I go about doing that. Please find the animation in below link.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyBvLJ

Comment: it's going to be much easier to create an animated balloon than to try to program the animation in the browser.. This is your original fiddle with a different image and looks very realistic: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYvOpe

Comment: @Pamblam Looks very Good! If you could elaborate that in the answer. I can mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to animate the path of the animation, use an online tool or Photoshop to create an animated balloon image.

This one looks nice in your [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYvOpe) :)

```
$('.parachute').animate({bottom: "1500px"}, 5000);
```

[image]